# How to enable/disable and/or show/hide GWT MenuItem

Tags: gwt, menuitem

I am using GWT 2.5.1

I have been struggling with this for hours now. How do you disable and/or hide a MenuItem in GWT.

```
menuItem.setEnabled(false); // DOES NOT WORK !!!
menuItem.setVisible(false); // DOES NOT WORK !!!
UIObject.setVisible(menuItem.getElement(), false); // DOES NOT WORK !!!
menuItem.setScheduledCommand(null); // DOES NOT WORK !!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hide/Show item**: You can remove a MenuItem with `MenuBar.removeItem(MenuItem)`. If you want to show it again, you can use `MenuBar.insertItem(MenuItem, index)`.

- **[Update]** I also tried `menuItem.setVisible(false)` and it works as expected (item is hidden).

**Disable item**: I'm not sure, why `menuItem.setEnabled(false)` doesn't work for you.

Take a look at the following example. I tested it with GWT 2.5.1 and it works.

```
FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
final MenuBar menubar = new MenuBar();
final MenuItem item = menubar.addItem("item one", new ScheduledCommand() {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        Window.alert("item one clicked");

    }
});
menubar.addItem("item two", new ScheduledCommand() {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        Window.alert("item two clicked");

    }
});

panel.add(menubar);

// Disable execution of command
Button buttonDisable = new Button("Disable item");
buttonDisable.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        item.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
panel.add(buttonDisable);

// Hide/Remove the item from the menubar
Button buttonHide = new Button("Hide item");
buttonHide.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        menubar.removeItem(item);

    }
});
panel.add(buttonHide);
RootPanel.get().add(panel);
```

Comment: Ok. I had the menu itself being a singleton class and I do not know why but changing it to an instance changed everything so now the methods work.